# How I can create vector maps for using on react apps

Tags: javascript, vector, maps, jvectormap

I wan't create data management system and I need vector maps for the visualizing some data with color gradients
[Gradient map of USA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvhWz.png)

(I try download existing vector maps but I can't find it for my country *(Turkmenistan)*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.